# Unit testing for iOS projects

Tags: ios, unit-testing, automated-tests

I'm still relatively new to iOS development and also an absolute stranger to any kind of testing that is not compile, run, and check whatever comes to your mind.

This is obviously a weakness on any developer's profile and I'm decided to get ride of it now that interesting, real projects are coming my way.

In my quest to look for the best approach to go from 0 to 100 as soon (and well) as possible I'm coming to the specialized community to get your feedback.

At the same time I'm asking for your tips I'm also getting into Amazon to look for well-reviewed books on the subject and Google to get the rest.  I'm just coming here to gather the feedback of those willing to spare a minute or to so I can probably hit jackpot with a great advise and better plan my learning strategy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats right. For my job testing and test driven development is indispensable.

I often use Java and JUnit, but for Objective-C and XCode I think this screencast is a very good start: http://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-tdd/

Since I watch this screencast I use [OCHamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/OCHamcrest) and [OCMockito](https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito) (both explaind in this screencast) as well as [SenTestingKitAsync](https://github.com/nxtbgthng/SenTestingKitAsync) for testing asynchronous functions.

I think the [Clean Code book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) is a must have for every developer. There is a chapter about testing.