# What is the _ _Tests folder in Xcode for

Tags: ios, xcode

What is the _ _ _Tests folder in Xcode for?

Every project (iOS) in Xcode has the following structure but I don't recall seeing the _ _ _Tests folder before. Does anyone know what this folder is for (see folder and files in bold)?

MainFolder
|
|_ProjectName
|
|*projectName.xcodeproj

|

|*_**ProjectNameTests**
..|- ***en.lproj***
..|- ***ProjectNameTests-Info.plist***
..|- ***ProjectNameTests.m***

The reason for this question is becuase I had to rename a project in Xcode and this folder is the only folder that didn't change and I was wondering if I will ever need this files or can they be deleted.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are separate classes with boiler plate code for unit tests. They don't do anything unless you run them explicitly. Notice there is also another project target as well. They're there to encourage you to write unit tests :-) If you never do anything with the tests or the target they refer to you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but how often or how important is to do unit tests when developing for iOS? Sorry but abusively unit testing is out of my knowledge. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355830/unit-testing-for-ios-projects | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030858/use-of-unit-test-in-xcode-5

Comment: It really depends on your application and needs. Unit testing pros/cons are a philosophy question. They can be useful, but they can also be a pain in the butt.

Comment: Cool, I will look into it more and make my own decision on whether I will be unit testing or not. Thanks a lot.